# Error while installing Airflow in windows using pip

Tags: python, cmd, pip, airflow

I am trying to install Airflow using the below command:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

The above command is taken from https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/installation.html.

But I am getting the following error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ,C:\Users\ASHISH~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0i7_2mfu\apache-airflow\
```

I already went through the related answers and tried almost everything, but it didn't work in case of Airflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is with GPL, see your error message it says :

RuntimeError: By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs a GPL dependency (unidecode). To avoid this dependency ***set SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes*** in your environment when you install or upgrade Airflow. To force installing the
GPL version set AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE

create an environment variable, set its name "SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE" and set its value "yes". upgrade your pip then install apache-airflow

Comment: Hi same problem here. I did it but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I got this to run in Windows 10 using PowerShell 5 command line. I've had issues when it comes to the Integrated Script Editor (ISE) installing other packages.

As part of the environment, instead of an independent variable, I'm defining a new variable called SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE and setting the value of it equal to yes. This means that as the install proceeds it's able to discover that value and continue with the installation.

```
$env:SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE="yes"
pip install apache-airflow
```

This command indicates I do **NOT** want to use the GPL dependency as described in the [installation process](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html).

Make sure to pick the [right packages](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html#extra-packages) for you, as in my example I just installed the default option. That might look like pip install apache-airflow[mssql,mysql]